# A constant sequence converging to a different limit

Tags: geometry, analysis, limits

[image: image 1][image: image 2][image: image 3]
Figure $1$ shows a equilateral triangle with unit side, so the sum of two arms is $2$. Figure $2$ is obtained from figure $1$ by connecting mid points of each sides giving two equilateral triangles with sides of length $\frac{1}{2}$ and the sum is again $2$. By the same process we got figure $3$ with total sum is $2$(shown in the figure).

> That is at each step we are getting sum of sides as $2$ but as $n\to \infty$ all the smaller triangles falls down to the base whose length is $1$ but accordingly it should be $2$. How is this possible??

I was asked this question a year ago by a professor but yet I have no answer.

Answer (score 2):

What is constructed here in the limit is much like a fractal curve, in which the curve length measurement depends on the scale on which the measurement is done.

Whenever the scale of measurement is much smaller than the height of the triangles, the length you get (by counting the number of boxes the curve enters and multiplying by the side of a box) is indeed $2$.

But whenever the scale is greater than the height of the triangles, the length you get is $1$.

The reason this appears to be a paradox is that when you draw diagrams, you mentally picture a length measured by drawing arbitrarily small boxes (getting a length of 2); but in the limit as $n\to\infty$, you can't draw small enough boxes, and any finite measurement scale gives a length of $1$.

BTW, the usual interesting fractal curves have the property that the length changes with scale in a more interesting way; but the idea is similar.